# Invoke Method with Linq Expression Parameter

Tags: c#, linq, reflection

I have method:

```
public IFluentBuilder<TValue> Setup<TValue>(Expression<Func<TOptions, TValue>> selector)
```

That I can call with:

```
Setup(obj => obj.Property).DoSomething()
```

How can I call `DoSomething`, a member of `IFluentBuilder`, through reflection when I have a `FieldInfo` or `PropertyInfo`, and `MethodInfo`.

Comment: OK, what if I have MethodInfo.

Comment: Or this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21701054/861716